# knockout dropdown

Tags: knockout.js

I am having trouble getting the selected item of a bound drop down list.

```
<p>
  Your Group: 
  <select data-bind="options: availableGroups, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'GroupId', value: selectedGroup, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
</p>
<p>
  I am visible
  You have chosen <span data-bind="text: selectedGroup() ? selectedGroup().Name : 'Nothing'"></span>
</p>
```

When I choose something from the drop down list, I would like to get the text of the selection, not the value. I am very new to knockout and trying to get a handle on this. I've created a fiddle for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/voam/FjRxn/

Comment: Why dont you just use dropdowns text value?

Comment: I now see that I was trying have knockout build the dropdown list with the option values all set to the groupid field in the generated markup, which isn't necessary.  So even though the values aren't set in the markup, when I retrieve the selected item I can get the GroupId field as part of the selected group object.

Answer (score 2):

For your original question @Pete's answer is right, but since you need to preserve GroupId as the value you could do [this (modified fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/FjRxn/42/).

First the `selectedGroup` property was renamed to `selectedGroupId`.

Then a new computed observable `selectedGroup` was defined based on the `selectedGroupId`:

```
self.selectedGroup = ko.computed(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    if (groups[i].GroupId == self.selectedGroupId())
      return groups[i];
  }
  return null;
});
```

Also the `var self = this` was defined

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to post a solution I've been using recently to solve this issue.  It utilizes binding handlers (valueAppendText and textFromOption) and appends an observable to the observable being tracked by the drop down.  This solution isn't complete, but demonstrates the idea of not using adding a computed to get the drop down text.  This solution also utilizes jQuery, which could be removed, but since I use jQuery in my projects (mostly), I left it in.  The jsFiddle link below demonstrates the functionality.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/FjRxn/65/

Markup:

```
<select data-bind="options: availableGroups, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'GroupId', valueAppendText: selectedGroup, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>

<p>
    I am visible
    You have chosen <span data-bind="textFromOption: selectedGroup"></span>
    <div>
        Group Id: <span data-bind="text: selectedGroup"></span>
    </div>
</p>
```

Binding Handlers:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.valueAppendText = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
      var $element, newValueAccessor, observable, setText;

      observable = valueAccessor();
      observable.selectedOptionText = ko.observable(null);
      newValueAccessor = function() {
        return observable;
      };
      $element = $(element);
      setText = function() {
        return observable.selectedOptionText($element.find("option:selected").text());
      };
      setTimeout(setText, 5);
      $element.change(function() {
        return setText();
      });
      return ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, newValueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
      return ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context);
    }
  };

  ko.bindingHandlers.textFromOption = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
      var newValueAccessor, observable;

      observable = valueAccessor();
      newValueAccessor = function() {
        if (ko.isObservable(observable.selectedOptionText)) {
          return observable.selectedOptionText();
        }
        return observable();
      };
      return ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, newValueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<select data-bind="options: availableGroups, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'GroupId', value: selectedGroup, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

To:

```
<select data-bind="options: availableGroups, optionsText: 'Name', value: selectedGroup, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

Comment: I also need to preserve the GroupId as the value field of the options, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use subscribe function on your observable selectedGroup. I have also created another observable as "selectedGroupId".

On subscribe event i assign value of GroupId to new observable "selectedGroupId"

```
 self.selectedGroup.subscribe(function(item)
     {
          debugger;
          self.selectedGroupId(item.GroupId);
          return item.Name;
      });
```

Please see updated Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FjRxn/50/)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to remove the optionsValue binding from your element.  It will then store the whole object in the observable and you can get to all of your properties.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FjRxn/105/)

```
<select data-bind="options: availableGroups, optionsText: 'Name',
value: selectedGroup, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use @pomber's answer, with a small edit.

```
self.selectedGroup = ko.computed(function(){
  return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.availableGroups(), function(grp) {
    return grp.GroupId == self.selectedGroupId();
  }
}, this);
```

I don't like using for-loop in computed observables.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLd2xmqb/1/)